# How to create responsive list item in recyclerView with fixed height and width

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-gridlayout

So basically I want to create list items like this using grid layout in recyclerView
[image]

So if I fixed my height and width of the list item it the content within it is not fitted and also it becomes unresponsive something like this

[image]

and if I make its height and width to match parent it becomes responsive but couldn't achieve the required list item that I want

[image]

So how can I achieve a layout like the first picture which is responsive as well?

My list item code with fixed height and width

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/cardView1"
  android:layout_width="@dimen/_166sdp"
  android:layout_height="@dimen/_195sdp"
  app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_20sdp"
  app:cardElevation="0dp"
  app:cardMaxElevation="0dp"
  android:backgroundTint="@color/light_gray"
  android:layout_margin="@dimen/_4sdp"
  app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
  app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
  app:contentPadding="10dp">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_120sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/list_item_image_view_bg"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/school_bag"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/light_gray"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/itemName_TextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
            android:text="School Bag"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/inExchange_TextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/list_exchange_item_bg"
            android:text="Rs. 400"
            android:padding="@dimen/_6sdp"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_8ssp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/institutionName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_4sdp"
            android:text="University of Sindh"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_8ssp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Comment: Make your row item parent layout height to *WRAP_CONTENT* and apply fix height to imageview.

Comment: yeah I have already given that but the output is like third picture that I have given

Comment: But this *android:layout_height="@dimen/_195sdp"* should be *wrap_content*

Comment: yeah I had done width to match_parent and height to wrap_content and output is third picture given above

Comment: So isn't it correct ?

Comment: no, because I want output like the first picture

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238694/discussion-between-piyush-and-mayra).